# mysql could not connect user@remotehost (111)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Tried all - **Server version: 5.7.29-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)**

1) GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb . * TO 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypasswd' WITH GRANT OPTION;

2) FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

3) Restarted MySQL

4) edited config vim /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf [ commented #bind-address ]

5) Checked the Grant column in User accounts through PHPmyadmin and is set to YES

6) Firewall is disabled.

7) Failed == mysql -h eu-ce.compute.internal -u myuser -p

8) Done restarting MySQL whenever needed [ port is the default : 3306 ]

**nmap hostname -p 3306**

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-01-31 09:52 UTC
Nmap scan report for hostname (xxx.xx.xx.xxx)
Host is up (0.00028s latency).

PORT     STATE  SERVICE
3306/tcp closed mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.04 seconds
```

Tried a lot of options,

Is there anything else that I am missing here to connect a DB from a remote host.?

Comment: What about the port?

Comment: @tcadidot0 default 3306

Comment: @gordon-linoff Do you have anything on this?

Comment: Have you tried to set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Tried commenting and changing to 0.0.0.0 (btw it was the same already )

Comment: What's the output of nmap remotehost -p 3306?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server is listening internally only.

Removing the line bind-address 127.0.0.1 from mysql cnf file.

Or try with to change port 3306 to different one in mysql cnf file.

and restart your mysql server.

I hope this will work for you.